# Odoo.sh page loading too slow on mobile

Tags: performance, lazy-loading, pagespeed, bottleneck, odoo.sh

On mobile phone, the most simple Odoo page loads far too slowly (Odoo.sh v13)

For instance, for the simple contact page form:

https://www.samalife.fr/contact
Page Speed Test :  score 35 / 100
https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.samalife.fr%2Fcontact

And it's even worse for a normal page content including images and videos :
https://www.samalife.fr/bas-du-dos
Page Speed Test :  score 28 / 100

The speed diagnostic points these bottlenecks :

- JS SCRIPTS ( 2,4 s )
  .../web.assets_common_lazy.js
  .../web.assets_frontend_lazy.js
- CSS SCRIPTS ( 2,4 s )
  .../web.assets_common.css
  .../web.assets_frontend.css
- UNUSED CSS SCRIPTS ( 1,6 s )
  .../web.assets_common.css
  .../web.assets_frontend.css
- SERVER RESPONSE TOO SLOW ( 0,8 s )

Is there a way to improve the different aspects involved in theses slow page load on mobile : js, css, server response ?

- How to implement lazy loading for css and javascript files ?
- How to implement compression in Odoo to minimze css and javascript files ?
- Does Odoo.sh provide alternative hosting packets for higher performance ?

Comparatively, for the same page (contactus), the rosehosting demo :
https://odoo-demo.rosehosting.com/contactus
get a score of 70 / 100

Comment: hi @sylvain! could you find any solution for that?